# Executing Maven 3 goals in order

Tags: maven, maven-3, build-automation

I have several Maven projects - a web service, which depends on several libraries.

When I add a new feature and want to deploy the web service to the server, I usually need to build these libraries in the correct order, i. e.

1. Go to the directory of library A.
2. Do `mvn clean install` there.
3. Go to the directory of library B.
4. Do `mvn clean install` there.
5. Go to the directory of the web service.
6. Do `mvn clean install` there.
7. Do `mvn cargo:redeploy`

The process must stop, if any of these steps end with a build failure (most of the time the builds are successful).

How can I automate this process (make one action instead of 7) in a clean way?

I'm using Git (hosted at Beanstalk) for version control and Amazon EC2 as a web app server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a build server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (or [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)) and trigger 'web service' project build when 'library B' has been built and trigger 'library B' project build when 'library A' has been built. Then trigger a build of 'library A'.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use one and the same Tomcat server for CI and for running my web service?

Comment: Yes, you can!!! See http://jenkins-le-guide-complet.batmat.cloudbees.net/html/sect-running-hudson-standalone.html